# Assistance with undefined stdclass error

Tags: php, mysql

I bought a script and developer is not responding after I paid(1 hour they said of work to tell me below) them to modify code.  I wanted to duplicate a field in the existing code by copy and past but of course this did not work.  The code I want to duplicate is:

```
<td class="dt2 dt0"><?php echo $this->lang->line('Description');?>:</td>
<td class="dt2" colspan="3"><?php echo wordwrap($job->description,100,"<br>",true); ?></td>                                   
</tr>
```

The code they gave me to add is:

```
<tr class="">
    <td class="dt2 dt0"><?php echo $this->lang->line('description2');?>:</td>
    <td class="dt2" colspan="3"><?php echo wordwrap($job->description2,100,"<br>",true); ?></td>                                      
</tr>
```

Then the told me to goto phpmyadmin and query database with:

```
ALTER TABLE 'jobs' ADD 'description2' text COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL AFTER 'description',COMMENT=";
```

When I do this code the output value is same for duplicate as the original.  If I change the duplicated `$job->description2` like they said I get error on page:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$description2
>
> Filename: job/view_job.php
>
> Line Number: 427

So I figured since I bought the code from them on their website that they would have been helpful, but obviously its  not their code and keep asking me for ftp to my server to fix it so I am leary.

I searched on here about std error and seen examples or adding a new stdclass:

```
$jobs=new stdClass();
$jobs->name='discription';
$jobs->status=1;)
```

but it did not do anything for error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the property "description2" just does not exist in the `$job` object. I think your developer must also provide you with a new Job Class. Do you have any cache in your project that you could refresh?

Also you could use `var_dump($job)` too see what properties this object actually have. Of course you can simply add a new StdClass $job and add a property "description2" but i am sure this would not be the intended use.

Comment: I am not sure.  Where would I do the var_dump?  Create a php file and add it?  I also found this is the form for the input: <p>
           <textarea rows="1" name="description" cols="5" maxlength="2"><?php echo set_value('description'); ?></textarea>
                       
         </p>
        <?php echo form_error('description'); ?>

Comment: You can place a var_dump anywhere wrapped in php tags. It's just temporary and to help you to see whats inside $job. I think you need to duplicate the above code too with the "description2" value – but it's only a guess at this point.

Comment: I did the var_dump and it returned NULL.  when I remoed the $ it returned string(3) "job".

Comment: So, NULL shows you that there is actually nothing in $job at this point. You should definitely read some basics. I think this would be a good starting point: http://tut.php-quake.net/en/

Comment: I found this answer also but i will do the reading you suggested.  I just found out it uses something called code igniter also.  Null answer maybe from stackoverflow google:The object is implemented "lazily", i.e. it does not retrieve data from the server until it's actually required (i.e. you access something from the result object).

var_dump doesn't seem to trigger the property getters so they are shown as null.

Comment: last question, so the class is Job not description or description2 what will they be called? object or array?